# Cannot set password for elastic user

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following [this post](https://medium.com/@jitendrashah1015/elasticsearch-es-cluster-setup-with-high-availability-and-rbac-enabled-kibana-b5f4e54c4631), security session to set up a new password for elastic user. Running `./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive` gave:

```
Failed to determine the health of the cluster running at http://es-ip-1:9200
Unexpected response code [503] from calling GET http://es-ip-1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Cause: master_not_discovered_exception

Unexpected response code [503] from calling PUT http://es-ip-1:9200/_security/user/apm_system/_password?pretty
Cause: Cluster state has not been recovered yet, cannot write to the [null] index

ERROR: Failed to set password for user [apm_system].
```

I entered the same password for all these `elastic,apm_system,kibana,kibana_system,logstash_system,beats_system,remote_monitoring_user`. What wrong did I do here, logging in elastic with new password doesn't work. Thanks.

**Update**

Config is the same on both nodes, except the `network.host` which is the private IP address of each node

elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: es-ip-1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [es-ip-1, es-ip-2, es-ip-3]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, gotta copy the cert to all the nodes, in this case it's `elastic-certificates.p12`.